# How to count number of rows that corresponds to the ID given two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables: 1) Places 2) Reviews

Table examples are below:

**PLACES**

```
ID   |  NAME
============
1    |  Joe
2    |  Cat
3    |  Dog
```

**REVIEWS**

```
PLACE_ID | REVIEW_ID| REVIEW_CONTENT 
====================================
1        | 1000     |  "it's good" 
1        | 1001     |  "aweful place"
3        | 1002     |  "good place"
```

PLACE_ID is my foreign key and I want to count number of review contents per each ID in PLACES table.

- As you can see,

1. there are 2 review contents in REVIEWS table for place id 1 ("Joe")
2. there are 0 review contents in REVIEWS table for place id 2 ("Cat")
3. there are 1 review contents in REVIEWS table for place id 3 ("Dog")

- The result should look like

**RESULT**

```
PLACE_ID | NAME | COUNT
=======================
1        | Joe  |  2
2        | Cat  |  0
3        | Dog  |  1
```

**Can someone please help how to count number of rows (e.g number of review contents) that has same foreign key (e.g. PLACE_ID), given two tables?**

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

This is basic SQL.  Please do some reading on simple aggregations.

```
SELECT P.ID as PLACE_ID, 
    P.NAME as NAME,
    COUNT(R.ID) as COUNT
FROM PLACES P
LEFT JOIN REVIEWS R
ON P.ID = R.PLACE_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - using `left join` and `aggregation`

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,count(r.id) as cnt
from place p left join reviews ON p.id = r.place_id
group by p.id, p.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Join both the tables and perform a aggregation to count the number of reviews for each ID available in Place table. You can find the code below.

```
Select A.PLACE_ID,
       A.Name,
       count(REVIEW_ID) COUNT
From Places A
Left Join Reviews B
on A.ID = B.PLACE_ID
group by A.PLACE_ID,
         A.Name
```